# Is it possible to factorize this polynomial without using software?

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

Is it possible to find the factors of this polynomial without using software like octave and matlab? $$8x^3+15x^2-16x-20$$
If you can do it, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here.  There  aren't any rational roots...Of course there are exact methods for solving cubics but they are cumbersome and people tend to avoid them.  Numerical methods are easy enough.

Comment: Over which field do you want to factorize that ? If it is over $\mathbb Q$ , the rational root theorem does the job.

Comment: @Peter thanks for replying, there are no rational roots .. i tried that method. Are they any other methods?

Comment: @lulu thanks for replying, i don't much about Math and i am here to learn. could you elaborate on one those exact methods or the number method you mentioned?

Comment: [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) gives an exact solution to cubics (using square roots of expressions in the coefficients).  Worth looking at, and theoretically very interesting,  but the solutions it gives tend to be [very ugly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+8x%5E3%2B15x%5E2-16x-20%3D0).  Since you'll need numerical methods to get the radicals anyway, people usually avoid the exact formula.

Comment: Note:  to illustrate how ugly the Cardano solutions are, take a look at the Wolfram Alpha computation I linked to and, just from looking at the exact forms,  decide which of those three roots are real.

Comment: thanks @lulu for the link.

Comment: thanks @Moo for the link.

Comment: Those exact methods actually are almost never used. There is even a more complicated full solution for degree $4$. For degree $5$ , we already need "bring radicals" and so on. Forget all this and use numerical approaches , if you want to find the real or complex roots.

Comment: @Peter thanks .. i didn't know forums could be this helpful